# How to check MySql database is email exists using C#, and if not then redirect?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, email

Simply put, I am creating an app that the user will need to have a gmail account to access.  How can I check the database to see if the user email exists, and if not then redirect to Google homepage?

Here is the code I am using to get the email address:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (null != principal)
            {

                foreach (Claim claim in principal.Claims)
                {
                    if (claim.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")
                    {
                        Session["UserEmail"] = claim.Value;
                    }

                    //Response.Write("CLAIM TYPE: " + claim.Type + "; CLAIM VALUE: " + claim.Value + "</br>");
                }
            }
        }
```

In order to get the email address, this is how I need to get it.  Convoluted, yes.  But this was over a week of working to get it so I am proud that at least this part works :)

I know that I need an `if` below the code, I am just not sure what the query would be.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you try to implement oauth? what's the point of you redirecting to google's registration page? take a look to this resource, I guess that approach is more standard https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding this as an answer because I am just shy of the reputation needed to post comments.  This is a comment more than an answer and for that I apologize.

You aren't clear on *what* "database" you are wanting to check.  Are you wanting to query Google to see if their email address is valid?  Or just see if the email address contained in Session["UserEmail"] is a gmail address (i.e., an '@gmail.com' address?

BTW, that for...each you have there will overwrite Session["UserEmail"] each time it iterates so in effect you'll always get the last value in the collection even if it's empty (or null?).  You can short-circuit any further iteration with a break; statement, but think about what you're doing here and under which circumstances you want to redirect them.  The way you are heading, it's going to be:  "If the principal's last claim doesn't have a Google address, redirect them to Google".  I doubt that's what you really want to do.

Finally, I'm not sure who your users are, but in general, it's <strike>sort of</strike> completely obnoxious to insist that users have email from a specific provider, a specific browser, a specific screen resolution, etc.   If this is for the general public, ditch that gmail requirement (though I personally use and love gmail).

Comment: I am sorry, I should have elaborated... There is a users table in the MySql database that has all the users email addresses. I would like to run a `scalar count` and see if the email address is there.  If it returns `0` then redirect to Google.  Anything else would just make the program continue to run.

As for the gmail requirement, that is direct from the client.  She loves Google and will be providing ChromeBooks as part of her package to the users.  The program is for those in senior homes to keep connected to their families.  I agree, its a completely obnoxious, but thats what she wants.